# Eclipse: Generic Predicates Compilation Error

Tags: java, eclipse, java-stream, predicate

I have this code:

```
public Argument0 onlyIf(Predicate<Pair<Entity, Context>> predicate) {
    return new Argument0(context -> elements.apply(context)
            .map(node -> Pair.of(node, context))
            .filter(predicate)
            .map(Pair::getLeft));
}
```

Eclipse is giving me this error exactly in ".filter" method call:

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57MTP.png)

As you can see the error does not make sense, because basically "predicate" variable is compatible with the required parameter for "filter".

```
predicate type: Predicate<        Pair<          Entity,Context>>
parameter type: Predicate<? super Pair<? extends Entity,Context>>
```

I changed to IntelliJ and the error is not shown, and, when I excecute Maven to compile the project it works.

Is there any Eclipse configuration that allowes me to run out of that error?

P.D. I cannot change that code because of is an inherit project and it will imply a lot of changes in the entire source code.

Comment: Yes, ECJ has some problems with type inference.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to solve this?